# Android companies api pricing?

Tags: android

How do i know if an api is free for use or has a price?.

I like to use some companies waze,whatsapp,facebook,gmail with my app but was unable to find any information about pricing.

Does opening an app using iframe cost too?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to type `name_of_software` + `api` in google. For example: `Waze Api` led me [here](https://developers.google.com/waze/) and `Facebook API` led me [here](https://developers.facebook.com/).

For Waze, you can look into becoming a [broadcaster](https://www.waze.com/broadcasters), which will give you access to their resources.

Try around, experiment and see what's out there and if they offer price information or not.

Comment: i found those sites before yet didnt find any price information (i think waze is free but for facebook i cant find any information)

Comment: that facebook link takes u to their api page and u can go https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android, download the sdk, and then https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ to follow the instructions on how to use it in an app. using facebook login/signup is free. same with gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android which is also free